# Post to facebook page as Admin

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am using Cordova [facebook](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) plugin to post on facebook page as admin.

I am having all permissions which are required to post on facebook page. Following is the list of permission I am having:

`email, manage_pages, public_profile, publish_actions, publish_pages`

I am trying to post on page using my app but everytime it post with user token and not with page token.

Code I tried:

//Gives list of pages user manage

```
$$('#apiTest_fb').on('click', function () {
                facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me/accounts", ["manage_pages"], 
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data[0].name))  
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                        //fb_pages(response);                                   
                        alert("Manage Pages Permission granted");
                        },
                    function (response)
                    {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
                    }); 
            });
```

//Dynamic dropdown of user pages

```
$$('#apiTest_fb_pages').on('click', function () {
                facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me/accounts", ["manage_pages"], 
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data[0].name))  
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                        //fb_pages(response);

                            var select = document.getElementById("selectPage");
                            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
                                var opt = response.data[i].name;
                                var page_val = response.data[i].id;
                                var el = document.createElement("option");
                                 el.textContent = opt;
                                 el.value = page_val;
                                 select.appendChild(el);
                            }

                        },
                    function (response)
                    {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.name))
                    }); 
            });
```

//on select pass get page access_token

```
$$('#selectPage').on("change", function(){
                var selectPage_id = $$(this).val();
                console.log(selectPage_id);
                window.localStorage.setItem("selectPage_id",selectPage_id);

            });

            $$('#FBActionPage').on('click', function () {           

                facebookConnectPlugin.api( window.localStorage.getItem("selectPage_id") + "?fields=access_token", ['publish_pages', 'manage_pages'], 
                    function (response) {
                        var pageToken = JSON.stringify(response.access_token);
                        //window.localStorage.setItem("fbtokenPage",JSON.stringify(response.access_token));                     
                        post_fbPage(pageToken);
                        },
                    function (response)
                    {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
                    }); 

            });
```

//post to face book

```
function post_fbPage(pageToken){

            console.log(pageToken); 

                facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
                        var url = '/'+ window.localStorage.getItem("selectPage_id") +'/feed?method=post&message=' + encodeURIComponent('Test') + '&link=' + 'impalz.co/JMR3a' + '&picture=' + 'www.impalz.com/images/affiliate-1.jpg' + '&caption=' + 'New Product' + '&description=' + 'we would love to know your feedback' +'&access_token=' + pageToken;
                        facebookConnectPlugin.api(
                            url,
                            ['publish_pages', 'manage_pages'],
                        function (response) { console.log(response.id)},
                        function (error) { console.error(error); }
                        );
                    });
            };
```

This is how post look like:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I share post as admin using my app?

EDIT 1:

I tried removing `publish_actions` and removing and adding app from user tabs while posting on page, still it post with user token.  I debugged my access_token and following content I got:

[image: Screen_Shot]

EDIT 2:

I tried Passing my token to [facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) and its posting on my wall perfectly. How can I use PHP SDK to post on facebook Page?

I've already tried passing `page_token` and `page_id` to post on fb page using PHP SDK but it ain't working.

Code I tried to post on User Facebook Wall:

```
require_once('src/Facebook/autoload.php');

$token = $_POST["token"]; // Used AJAX to post data on server

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{ID}',
  'app_secret' => '{SECRET}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  'default_access_token' => $token, 
  ]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'User provided message',
  ];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $token);       

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

Comment: why not just remove publish_actions? not sure why you are trying to add it, you only need publish_pages for posting as page. would make debugging easier.

Comment: I tried remove `publish_actions`. But still it post using `user_token` even though I passes `page_token` while posting.

Comment: remove the app in your facebook settings and try again. i am sure publish_actions is still approved. and i am sure you are using a user token, i guess that sdk just adds the user token and ignores your own token parameter.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Still not sure how to pass page token. 
I've already tried removing app option

Comment: Maybe the plugin adds the user access token automatically to every request made or something … go check the docs and/or source code to see if there is an explicit option to pass a different access token,

Comment: How can I pass token explicitly ? I tried searching in docs but its no where mentioned.

Comment: Pop the access token being used in the network request in the access token debugger and see if it is a page access token or user access token https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token. Page access token will have a 'Profile ID' field. Also, as stated by everyone else in the thread, remove 'publish_actions' from your code and also the app from your settings https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications before trying again.

Comment: @Bangdel - Check Edit 1, I tried all as per your suggestion.

Comment: The access token seems fine. It probably is the plugin doing something strange.

Comment: With php sdk you can post to the page using the endpoint "/{page-id}/feed" https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed

Comment: Did you remove `publish_actions` and then try PHP? Put it back and it should work with PHP SDK v5.0

Comment: @Slartibartfast I removed `publish_actions` to tried getting token. You can check screenshot of access_token debugger. You can see all the details in screenshot.

Comment: I meant, it's compulsory to have publish_actions as a permission for page update

Answer (score 2):

You can have a never expiring token for your [fan page](https://www.facebook.com/navnishbhardwaj), that will solve your problem i guess.

Follow the simple steps:

- Get the admin's(i.e. your's) extended token (2 months validity). Go
  though the link to get the `long-lived token`.

[Extending tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)

- Get the never expiring access token for any page using this token

  facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");

(You can use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check the validity of the token).

Posting as Admin is easy but posting as Page requires more work from your side. To post as Page we need the following permissions:

```
publish_stream
manage_pages
```

We need the `manage_pages` permission to get the page access token so we can post on its behalf. And this is how we do it:

```
<?php
// This code is just a snippet of the example.php script 
// from the PHP-SDK <https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php>
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'app_id',
  'secret' => 'app_secret',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $page_id = 'page_id';
    $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
    if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
            'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
        );
        $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
    } else {
        $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
        if( !array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) || 
            !array_key_exists('manage_pages', $permissions['data'][0])) {
            // We don't have one of the permissions
            // Alert the admin or ask for the permission!
            header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream, manage_pages")) );
        }

    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
}

// ... rest of your code
?>
```

**Using the Javascript-SDK
Achieving the same with only client-side technology:**

```
function postToPage() {
    var page_id = '000000000000';
    FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
        if(resp.access_token) {
            FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
                'post',
                { message: "I'm a Page!", access_token: resp.access_token }
                ,function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Using /me/accounts connection**

If you are building some sort of a [CMS](http://www.navnishbhardwaj.com) where the admin wants to select one of the pages to update its status, then using the /me/accounts is better you can list the pages and save their access_token in one API call.

```
$page_id = "XXXXXXXXX";
$page_access_token = "";
$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
    if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
        $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
        break;
    }
}
if( !empty($page_access_token) ) {
    $args = array(
        'access_token'  => $page_access_token,
        'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
    );
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
    // sucess...
} else {
    // couldn't find the page!
}
```

Always communicate with your page fans as Page not as Admin, fans do know (and trust) your page (product) but not necessary you!

Comment: I've already tried getting extended page token for fan page and passing it to post on facebook page, but still it passes `user_token` to post. In question I've attached screenshot of extended_token which never expires. In PHP I am using [facebook-php-sdk-v4](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) which I guess is the stable release, Can you help me passing page token and posting using this v4 SDK?

Comment: I tried this code too https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 Its working well at my end. At first there were issues in setup but I used this link for help https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0 I would like you to go through this link. Complete documentation, installation instructions, and examples are available here.